# ReCaptcha error on webbrowser

Tags: javascript, vb.net, recaptcha

I'm trying to open a simple website on webbrowser in VB.net, on my formLoad I have the follow code

```
 Dim appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)

            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appName, 11000, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = True
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/PessoaJuridica/CNPJ/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Solicitacao2.asp")
```

In this site have a ReCAPTCHA challenge, and when I try to load this page got the following error:

[image: Error]

I'm using Windows 7 and got internet explorer 8.

Comment: Instead of the built-it web browser control,try using CEFsharp...Hope that'll fix the problem

Comment: @zackraiyan I'll try this approach, thanks

Comment: @zackraiyan With CEFsharp the captcha shows but got a loop, the images keep refreshing everytime I click on then

Comment: The images will keep showing as the website can't verify your IP or device i guess(they just don't wanna believe you are a human)...i suggest you to show them your birth certificate ......jokes apart, try visiting another site that has a captcha like MediaFire to see if the problem occurs in other sites too...Let me know

Comment: @zackraiyan This loop is because the recapcha challenge was turned to a very dificult level, after i make the challenge about 10 times the recaptcha works... I think this approach will not resolve my problem at all but, that's all we got. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the CEFSharp approach, but the captcha challenge was turned in a hight level dificult, works but...
thanks @zackraiyan for the solution.

Comment: welcome and please know this...The fact that captcha became difficult was reported to google years ago...all google said was there might be some problem with the site having captcha